# setuptools installer fails in Docker build in Jenkins

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, setuptools

When I try to build a Docker image in Jenkins that includes installing my setuptools-enabled Python package, it stalls and then eventually fails when running `setup.py install`. It doesn't give any usefully explanatory error message.

```
Step 14/29 : COPY ipxecgi /tmp/ipxecgi
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2f92d493b2df
Step 15/29 : RUN /tmp/ipxecgi/setup.py install
 ---> Running in 917ccce3e0ab
running install
Checking .pth file support in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/
/usr/bin/python3 -E -c pass
TEST PASSED: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ appears to support .pth files
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating UNKNOWN.egg-info
writing top-level names to UNKNOWN.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to UNKNOWN.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing UNKNOWN.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing entry points to UNKNOWN.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing manifest file 'UNKNOWN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
[91mKilled
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c /tmp/ipxecgi/setup.py install' returned a non-zero code: 137
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
No emails were triggered.
Finished: FAILURE
```

/tmp/ipxecgi is the package source. It looks like this:

```
ipxecgi/
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── ipxecgi
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── main.py
    │   ├── nbconfig.py
    │   └── templates
    │       └── ipxe.jinja
    └── tests
        └── nbconfig_tests.py
```

Comment: What's in `/tmp/ipxecgi`?

Comment: @gdlmx I added that tree to the question.

Comment: I think something is wrong in your ipxecgi project. At least the setup.py contains some error so it "returned a non-zero code: 137". Without seeing the source of `setup.py`, nobody can tell.

Comment: To get more debugging output, set `DISTUTILS_DEBUG=1` in the environment